# update jboss7 in liferay 4.3.4

Tags: java, jboss, liferay, oracle12c

update oracle 12c so, update jdk 8, hibernate 5.2,spring framework 4.3.1 also jars  from jdk 7, hibernate 3. war file does not work with run.bat file that it gives error, so I will update jboss to eap 7.0 from jboss 4.0.5 ga, but there is liferay 4.3.4 in jboss 4.0.5. can liferay 4.3.4 work in jboss 7.0 and how to configuration jboss 7 eap?(ı am not using maven)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it's time not only to update your infrastructure, but also the applications. Liferay 4.3.4 has been released in 2007-11-05 and even the 4.3.x series had some more updates after this, but largely the 4.x version is outdated since 2008. Nobody has tested it with Java8, JBoss 7 etc. And, by all means - please put a little more effort into your questions to make it clear what you're actually asking about.

Comment: liferay portal ce 7 support jboss 6.4 or 7 ? or which liferay portal version supported jboss 6.4 or 7 with jdk 8, oracle 12c?

Comment: please edit your question instead of bringing up new questions in the comments.